# When I connect to work email from an outside device, how am I connecting?

Tags: networking, email, mobile-phone

If I send an email form my work email account from my Iphone, how is it connecting? Would it be possible to check the email header of the email sent form my phone and find the IP address and figure out where I was when I sent the email. For example, if I say I sent I was in New York when I sent an email would it be possible for someone to find out that I was actually in Chicago when I sent the message simply by looking at the IP address in the email header?

Comment: probably, yes. There is some ambiguity based on network configuration though. For instance, unless the Email server or relay is on your LAN, it will see the first public address in the chain between the sender and the server they are sending out from, as the originating IP, so its not always certain that the sender IP in the header is the actual sender, just the first public IP in the path. This is further compounded by geographically distributed LANs with point to point links between them. and if the relay is on the lan, it will likely see the sender correctly. there are lots of ifs here.

Answer (score 0):

If you "View Headers" on the receiving system, you will see an ordered list of all the systems your email has passed through. It's what makes debugging email routing problems possible, and lying about your location not foolproof.